# Why ejabberd web admin has less option on compile and install?

Tags: macos, makefile, ejabberd, make-install

I installed ejabberd on my mac my two different ways

1. Using installer from this [link](https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/).
2. Using source code from this [link](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd).

I got issue on installing by second method but I manage to install it but after install everything is fine but I don't know the admin user name and password by follow instruction from [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/579).  After login on web admin using new reset password I found very less option.

Web admin:
From Installation option 1 :-

[image]

From Installation option 2 :-

[image]
[image]

I want all the web admin option in second installation, please explain what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: you are doing nothing wrong .I  already installed from source code .There  was very less option  and I reinstalled it from installer.

Comment: So there is no way to add all these option ?

Comment: download and recompile ejabberd_web_admin.erl and keep binary file in ejabberd bin directory may fix your problem.

Comment: Mickaël Rémond solution solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not seem to be admin when you compile it from source. Your configuration is probably incorrect. Make sure your user is configured as admin in ejabberd configuration file.

Creating and configuring admin user is explained in ejabberd documentation: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/#creating-an-xmpp-account-for-administration

Comment: I didn't configure anything and I I don't know which user is default admin, Can you please guide me how to configure it correctly ?

Comment: It is explain in ejabberd documentation: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/#creating-an-xmpp-account-for-administration